# Status code 500 occurs in App Actions Test Tool (Android Studio)

Tags: android, app-actions

I'm getting a 500 error when deleting / creating a Preview using the App Actions Test Tool, which worked fine until a few days ago. I've uploaded an App bundle for internal testing, and I'm also logged into Android Studio with a Google Play Console account. I attached the error information below that is sent from App Actions Test Tool. Since there is not too much detail about the error 500, it would be very helpful if you could give me some advice.

Android Studio version:  Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675

App Action Test Tool Version: 3.6.0

Built-in Intent used: OPEN_APP_FEATURE

actions.xml :

```
<actions>
    <action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}"/>
        <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://projectname-actions.firebaseapp.com/all-tasks"/>

        <parameter name="feature">
            <entity-set-reference entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet" />
        </parameter>
    </action>

    <entity-set entitySetId="FeatureEntitySet">
        <entity  url="https://projectname-actions.firebaseapp.com/completed-tasks"
            name="completed tasks" alternateName="@array/completed_tasks_synonyms"/>
    </entity-set>
</actions>
```

arrays.xml :

```
<resources>
   <array name="completed_tasks_synonyms">
       <item>invocationName</item>
   </array>
</resources>
```

Steps for this issue to happen：

1. open App Actions Test Tool
2. (For Delete) Delete Preview -> Preview Deletion Error
3. (For Creation) Create Preview -> Preview Creation Error

Stacktrace:
20:34   App Actions Test Tool v3.6.0
Preview Deletion Error

```
        Status Code: 500
        Message: Internal error encountered.
        
        
        Create Actions.xml
```

20:34   App Actions Test Tool v3.6.0
Preview Creation Error

```
        Status Code: 500
        Message: Internal error encountered.
        
        
        Create Actions.xml
```

2022-04-29 20:42:09,290 [1514700]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Update Preview Request = {
"name": "androidActionPackages/com.sample.projectname/versions/preview",
"actionsXmlContents": "....",
"previewSettings": {
"invocationName": "invocationName",
"locale": "en"
},
"localizedResources": [{
"name": "completed_tasks_synonyms",
"resourceType": "STRING_ARRAY",
"value": ["invocationName"]
}],
"xmlContentType": "ACTIONS"
}
2022-04-29 20:42:13,501 [1518911]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JSONObject["details"] not found.
2022-04-29 20:42:13,501 [1518911]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Preview Creation Error

Status Code: 500
Message: Internal error encountered.

com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.exceptions.ActionsBuilderException: Preview Creation Error

Status Code: 500
Message: Internal error encountered.

```
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.api.HttpClient.updatePreviewV2(HttpClient.kt:129)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$execute$2.compute(AppActionsFrame.kt:94)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$execute$2.compute(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:854)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame.execute(AppActionsFrame.kt:67)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame.access$execute(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$createPreviewAndFetchIntentsTask$1.invoke(AppActionsFrame.kt:44)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$createPreviewAndFetchIntentsTask$1.invoke(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.AppActionsTaskBackgroundable.run(AppActionsTaskBackgroundable.kt:20)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

2022-04-29 20:42:13,502 [1518912]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675
2022-04-29 20:42:13,502 [1518912]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 11.0.11; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2022-04-29 20:42:13,502 [1518912]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Windows 10
2022-04-29 20:42:13,502 [1518912]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Plugin to blame: Google Assistant version: 2.2.0
2022-04-29 20:42:13,502 [1518912]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action: ActivateAppActionsToolWindow
2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Can't create preview
com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.exceptions.ActionsBuilderException: Preview Creation Error

Status Code: 500
Message: Internal error encountered.

```
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.api.HttpClient.updatePreviewV2(HttpClient.kt:129)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$execute$2.compute(AppActionsFrame.kt:94)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$execute$2.compute(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:854)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame.execute(AppActionsFrame.kt:67)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame.access$execute(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$createPreviewAndFetchIntentsTask$1.invoke(AppActionsFrame.kt:44)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.frames.AppActionsFrame$createPreviewAndFetchIntentsTask$1.invoke(AppActionsFrame.kt:29)
at com.google.assistant.plugin.appactions.ui.toolwindow.AppActionsTaskBackgroundable.run(AppActionsTaskBackgroundable.kt:20)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675
2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.11; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation
2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10
2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: Google Assistant version: 2.2.0
2022-04-29 20:42:13,503 [1518913]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: ActivateAppActionsToolWindow
2022-04-29 20:42:13,524 [1518934]   INFO - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - refreshing state, current state = WELCOME_PAGE

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, I've just run into the same issue and hence can't try out this feature.I also think it was you who reported it in on google issues. Just attaching a link for completeness: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230772377